# How can I sort a collection of custom entities?

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of custom entities which I need to sort in this order: valueOne, valueTwo, and valueThree.

Here is my code

```
public class AppRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Detail d1 = new Detail("valueOne");
        Detail d2 = new Detail("valueTwo");
        Detail d3 = new Detail("valueFive");
        Detail d4 = new Detail("valueTen");
        Detail d5 = new Detail("valueOne");
        Detail d6 = new Detail("valueOne");

        List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>(Arrays.asList(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6));

        Collections.sort(details);
        System.out.println(details);
    }
}
```

My entity class

```
public class Detail implements Comparable<Detail> {

    private String value; // there are three options: valueOne, valueTwo, and some other value

    public Detail(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Detail detail) {
        String val = detail.getValue();
        if (val.equals(this.value) && val.equals("valueOne")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (val.equals(this.value) && val.equals("valueTwo")) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // getter, setters, toString
}
```

I think that need help with `compareTo` method. In the end I need to get list in this order:

1. valueOne
2. valueOne
3. valueOne
4. valueTwo
5. valueFive

Comment: You could try using a Map where you can use those strings as keys and give them values in the form of integers such as valueOne -> 1. Then you can use your compareTo method to compare the values of those keys! If you only compare those strings, it will just sort them for you in the alphabetical order.

Comment: what kind of output to you get rigth now?

Comment: I don't have a fully featured answer for you. What I would do is this: I would introduce a string enum with the values of your strings. And in compare to I would simply compare their numeric equivalent. Or - bit easier - introduce a new attribute to the Detail class which is a simple int. In the constructor set the int value corresponding to the string given. So you introduce your own type of match between strings and some corresponding numerical value. In compareTo just compare the corresponding ints.

Comment: @Sam I am Now I have `[valueOne, valueTwo, valueFive, valueTen, valueOne, valueOne]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an Enum and compare ordinals:

```
enum ValidValues { valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree }
```

... and then:

```
public int compareTo(Object detail) {
    return Integer.compare(ValidValues.valueOf(this.value).ordinal(),
                           ValidValues.valueOf(((Detail)detail).value).ordinal());
}
```

For a larger number of values it might be worth it to do this with a collection or map, rather than an enum.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

See note at the end on possible better designs.

I suggest adding another field to the `Detail` class, populating that baeed on the desired sort order and `value`, and using this to sort.

```
public class Detail implements Comparable<Detail> {

    private String value;
    private int sortOrder;

    public Detail(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        if(value.equals("valueOne") {
            sortOrder = 1;
        }
        if(value.equals("valueTwo") {
            sortOrder = 2;
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
```

This makes `compareTo` simple:

```
public int compareTo(Detail detail) {
    if(this.sortOrder < detail.sortOrder) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(this.sortOrder == detail.sortOrder) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(this.sortOrder > detail.sortOrder) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Note:
The above is solution to your problem as it stands. However, you may have better options. If you are using Detail to represnet a fixed set of values, look at [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). `Enum`s in Java are very powerful and versatile. You can have a enum repsesenting a fixed set of values and use the enum in your `Detail` class.

If you may have a large set of values that are not predefined, you can have a `Map` that maps the sort order with the value.

```
private static Map<Int, String> sortOrder = new HashMap<Int, String>();

sortOrder.put(1, "valueOne");
...
```

And use this map sorting. Depending on your situation, you can popuklate this map from a database, a file on initialization or just dueing runtime.

Comment: Here is my result `[valueFive, valueTen, valueOne, valueOne, valueOne, valueTwo]`

Comment: @barbara Is this your entire set, your expected output or what you het when you try something? Also there was a typo in my code which I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple getter that return a numeric value based on your String value and simply return the difference of both numeric values in your `compare()` method (remember that `compare()` should return 0 if the two objects are equals, see [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) javadoc.

```
public static class Detail implements Comparable<Detail> {

    private String value; // there are three options: valueOne, valueTwo, and some other value

    public Detail(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Detail detail) {
        return this.getNumericValue() - detail.getNumericValue();
    }

    private int getNumericValue() {
        switch (this.value) {
            case "valueOne": return 1;
            case "valueTwo": return 2;
            default: return 3;
        }
    }

}
```